# Python: Append Multiple Rows in a Dataframe (For Loop)

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, concatenation, append

How do I append/concatenate the contents of a dataframe to an existing one within a for loop? beyond_threshold (example below) outputs multiple rows for each SN group and I want them all combined in a single dataframe.

```
for key, value in df.groupby(df['SN']):
    beyond_threshold = value[value.level>10]
```

Comment: check out `pandas.concat()`